# Указатель на тип (TypeObjectPointer) может быть null?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Читая про [упаковку/распаковку на Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2),

> Распаковка ссылочного типа в значимый подразумевает, что это должно
>   быть выполнено явно. При этом, необходимо во-первых, сначала
>   удостовериться, что тип упакованного объекта по ссылке соответствует
>   исходному, а во-вторых, скопировать поля данных упакованного объекта в
>   новую переменную данного типа. Как правило, проверку соответствия
>   типов осуществляют с помощью механизма генерирования и обработки
>   исключений, после чего копирование переносит внутренние данные
>   (поля) объекта из «кучи» в стек выполняемого приложения, где хранятся
>   его локальные переменные. Последовательность конкретных действий
>   сводится к следующим шагам:
>
> 1. если служебный указатель на упакованный значимый тип имеет значение
>      null, то генерируется исключение NullReferenceException,
> 2. если
>      упакованный объект не соответствует требуемому типу, то выбрасывается
>      исключение InvalidCastException.

наткнулся на то, что тут говорят:

***1. если служебный указатель на упакованный значимый тип имеет значение null, то генерируется исключение NullReferenceException.***

Я правильно понимаю, что под "Служебный указатель на упакованный значимый тип", следует понимать "Указатель на объект-тип (TypeObjectPointer)"? И если я прав, разве TypeObjectPointer может быть когда либо равным null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеется в виду скорее всего такой сценарий:

```
Object obj=(object)3;
obj=null;
var i=(int)obj;
```

А `TypeObjectPointer` по идее никогда не может быть Null'ом, так как он есть во всех объектах и без него тогда бы было неизвестно какого типа объект перед CLR.

Даже сам System.Type ссылается [сам](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21852665/4244707) на себя:

> Of course, the system.type object is an object itself and therefore it also has a type object pointer member in it, and it is logical to ask what this member refers to. It refers to itself because the system.type object is itself an "instance" of a type object.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вы понимаете неправильно. Type Object Pointer — вероятно, указатель на экземпляр класса `System.Type`, который создаётся компилятором для каждого класса, даже для абстрактного.

Есть [статья](https://aakinshin.net/ru/posts/typehandle/), которая рассказывает, как этот указатель можно извлечь из заголовка объекта.

Он не может быть равен `null` ни у какого объекта в куче.

О каком же *служебном* указателе речь? Попробуем найти исходник текст на английском языке. Это отрывок из [книги Джеффри Рихтера](https://books.google.ru/books?id=36tCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT208&lpg=PT208&dq=if+the++pointer+to+the+boxed+value+type+is+null,+then+a+NullReferenceException+is+thrown,&source=bl&ots=7k5zQilvM-&sig=ACfU3U3f4Q9FrSeWyNYtgCN3RSujAN9rZA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqpI2BpZ7mAhXlAxAIHdggDSEQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=if%20the%20%20pointer%20to%20the%20boxed%20value%20type%20is%20null%2C%20then%20a%20NullReferenceException%20is%20thrown%2C&f=false) CLR via C#:

> Internally, here's exactly what happens when a boxed value type instance is unboxed:
>   1. If the variable containign the reference to the boxed value type instance is null, a `NullReferencePointer` is thrown.

Как видите, никакого слова *служебный* в оригинале нет.

Речь конечно, идёт о том, что если вы пытаетесь привести `null` к значимому типу, такому как `int`, вы получите `NullReferencePointer`.

Вторая проблема текста в том, что он не обновлялся по всей видимости с 2003 года. Уже в версии .NET 2 появился тип `Nullable<T>`, который является значимым, но обрабатывается третьим способом. Если указатель на объект равен `null` и приводится к `int?` вы получите  корректный значимый объект `Nullable<Int32>` с установленным свойством `IsNull`.